# Word meaning places in a journey?

Tags: single-word-requests

In an journey or itinerary you have source/origin/departure locations, stops/intermediate locations, and your destination/arrival location.

Is there a single noun that means any location in a journey or itinerary?

"Stops" and "destinations" don't include where you start, so they are not suitable.

Comment: I think it would be useful to know what these intermediate stops are used for. Or could they be used for anything, and are you really looking for a single word that incorporates them all?

Comment: @Joachim a single word for all of them. If all the locations were airports I could say "all the airports" and it's clear I'm including the origin, not just the destinations/stopovers. But I am looking for a more generic word for any type of location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to work in the logistics industry, and our system would create "routes" composed of "**waypoints**". I think the word "waypoint" would fit your requirement; however, it's not a common everyday word, and it might be easier just to use "stops" and add the comment that you're using this to refer to the origin as well as the destinations.

Comment: Waypoint is probably the best match for what I mean, as it also includes the starting location. Thank you.

Comment: There's [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169657/position-between-the-origin-and-the-destination) asking for the points on a journey excluding start and end, and someone answered "waypoint" there as well. It can't be both, surely.

Comment: Stuart: I just checked the OED, and interestingly they have two senses: 1. "North American (originally U.S.). An intermediate stopping place on a journey or route" (which suggests it isn't the start or end) and 2. "Originally: the destination point of each leg of a long flight; the coordinates of any such point, esp. as generated and checked by a computerized navigation system. Subsequently also: a similar reference point or set of coordinates used in making a journey by sea or on land." -- I can only say that I did a lot of work in logistics and that's we called every point on a route.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a trip, consider **stopover location or point** :

Examples :
*Valence is a member of the "Cities of Art and History"
network, and a stopover point on the famous pilgrimage road to Saint Jacques de Compostelle.*

*the Port of Quebec Marina is the
ideal location to make a stopover with your family or your friends.*

Comment: Thanks, but stopover doesn't imply the origin as well.

Comment: If you refer to all you do between start and stop, you may use **stage**. Example: the different stages programmed for my 7-day tour in Italy are ...

Comment: Also, it should be noted that airlines tend to use *stopover* as a technical term, with a narrower meaning than it has otherwise.